# How do you select child-or-self (children + self)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

In XSL 1.0, descendant-or-self will select ALL descendants and the current node. What if you want to select only the immediate children and the current node (i.e. child-or-self)?

Is that possible with XPATH?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**In XPath 1.0 or later use**:

```
SomeExpression | SomeExpresion/node()
```

**In XPath 2.0 or later use**:

```
SomeExpression/(self::node()|node())
```

**An incorrect answer would be**:

```
SomeExpression | SomeExpression/*
```

because this selects only those children of `SomeExpression` that are elements, while `SomeExpression` may have other children too -- as text-nodes, comment nodes, processing-instruction nodes.

**Also incorrect is**:

```
./SomeExpression | ./*/SomeExpression
```

This doesn't select the immediate children of `./SomeExpression` and it doesn't select the immidiate children of `./*/SomeExpression`.

Comment: Note for those using standard JS, no major browsers support XPath 2.0

Comment: @ThatsJustCheesy In a browser one can use Saxon.js, which implements even XPath 3.1